# How to separate pattern circles from noise circles?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I have a set of points part of them belongs to pattern and others is noise. How can I filter them?
I think using the [ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/) library to find the position of the pattern closest to the points and as a result noises will also be known.

What else you can recommend?

Pattern:
[image: circles pattern]

Comment: Ceres library provides set of solvers. In order to use them you should first model your problem (i.e. write down the mathematical formulation of your problem). Then choose a method to solve your problem (e.g. gradient descent). And then implement the necessary codes needed for ceres to solve your problem (e.g. gradient of your problem model for gradient descent). This is how you can use ceres not just solving an arbitrary problem like this!

Comment: Is your problem domain an image? Or a set of points in R^2?

Comment: @Mohammad CostFunction for ceres is summ of minimal distances between transformed pattern and points. It's set of points, But it is no problem with ceres. I just asked any other situable methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a classification model for this problem, you need a feature vector `f[i]` which can be evaluated for a point `p[i]`. One feature that we can build is the distance of the point to its K Nearest Neighbors. Let's say we choose `k = 4`. And the feature vector will look like following pseudo code,

```
for i = 1 to count(PositivePoints)
  k = 4
  nn = KNN(p[i],k)
  for j= 1 to k
    vec = nn[j] - p[i]
    f[i][j] = norm(vec)
  end
end
```

In the code above, `f` is a matrix every row (`f[i]`) of which is a feature vector (of the point `p[i]`) and `norm` is [L2 norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) which is defined for vectors (similar to Euclidean distance). `PositivePoints` is the set of points that belong to the pattern.

Now you can build a likelihood of your model `p(y|F)`. i.e. if you are given the model `F` (infered by matrix `f`) then what is the likelihood of a point (`y`) to belong to the pattern. In order to do this for a general case, one would use [Maximum apostriori estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) or [Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).
But to keep it simple, let's build the `p(y|F)` as following,

```
if(norm(y - F) < t) then
  p(y|F) = 1
else
  p(y|F) = 0
```

in the pseudo code above, `t` is an arbitrary threshold which you can find our empirically which depends on the noise in the positive points, `y` is the interesting point which you want to know if it belongs positives and `F` is the model decided by following pseudo-code,

```
for j= 1 to k
  F[j] = median(f[:][j])
end
```

in the code above, `f[:][j]` resembles *j*th column of the matrix `f`, and `F[j]` is the distance to the *j*th neighbor which is the most common among the positive points. I chose median over mean since it is more robust to noise. Although from the image that you shared, it seems you do not have noise as such.